# Why my innertube is so big

Tags: tire, innertube

So my old tyre had markings 32-622 and 700x32c. I bought new tyre with those specs and that is fine. It fits perfectly on the rim.

But I bought inner tube with those specs and it seem it is way to big for the rim / tyre. I'm a missing something? What is the correct size inner tube for this tyre?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just one stroke with the pump will make the tube fit in.

Comment: Before you even start to insert the tube, give it a couple of pumps, so that it's not limp and flat.

Comment: In your photo, looks like the tube is roughly parallel to the bead.  Try shoving it into the tyre more, so its against the inside of the tread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sizes match, so according to the manufacturers you are on the safe side.

It’s not uncommon for tubes to be slightly too “long” (i.e. have a wider diameter). Maybe it’s because this tube also fits 635mm wheels and not just your 622mm.

Just try to “distribute” the excess length, so you don’t have one big kink in a single place. In your photo it’s also not fully inside the tyre.

Comment: Yep, it worked fine in the end. I think the thing was that it can also fit 635mm so it had some extra. First time inner tube was so much bigger so I go confused but "distributing" it out helped. Thanks a lot guys for your help!

Answer (score 6):

Don't worry. Try taking a square piece of rubber. If you stretch it in one direction, it will naturally try to become narrower in the other direction. When you pump your tyre, it will fit well. Also, a part of the tube is then farther from the rim – where the diameter is larger.